# Using Intent to launch a new fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences, android-jetpack

I know it sounds erroneous, "using intent to launch a new fragment?". You may say it should be activity, not fragment if we are talking about Intent. But according to the [JetPack Preferences](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings) [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/customize-your-settings) we can use Intent to launch a new fragment.

> **[Set an Intent](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/customize-your-settings#set_an_intent)**
>
> You can set an Intent on a Preference to launch a new
>   `Fragment`, `Activity`, or separate application whenever the Preference is
>   tapped. This is the same as using `Context.startActivity()` with a given
>   Intent.

As you can see no example provided about launching fragment with Intent. 
If there is a way to achieve this i would like to learn.
Because I am developing a single activity app with fragments, there is navigation component and bottom navigation menu. Trying to use a new activity changes lots of things.

I am just trying to open another fragment when user tap a Preference.

Comment: "I just trying to open another fragment when user tap a Preference" -- [set a listener on it](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/Preference#setOnPreferenceClickListener(androidx.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener)) and show the fragment in the listener.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, I am trying to solve in that way but according to the documentation there is another way.